# Flask server on development server works strangely

Tags: python, flask, embedded

I have been trying to create a **streaming** webserver in **flask** on my **Jetson Nano** board.

I made the following setup:

- Jetson board containing webserver. (Yes the webserver is Development server by flask, but i am just using 2-3 devices at a time)
- A Mikrotik router, to broadcast and connect to webserver using my smartphone.

I have also tried some threading and so, functionality for my webserver.
`CAP = image_capture.Camera()` create a CV object for videocapture and capture frames from the *nvarguscamerasrc*.

**Problem**:
So the problem is, I can use this web app on my phone, but when I use some other phone to connect, on typing the ip it just takes forever to load the page in phone browser. I can definitely say that python has received the request as it's visible in logs of webserver.

**What could be the exact problem, is it Router? my deployment? or webserver code as I'm executing a load of commands before `app.run()`**

**Any better profiling tools or methods that might help to figure out exact problem would be of great help.**

**Below is the `app.run()` section of the web app**

```py
if __name__ == '__main__':
    CAP = image_capture.Camera()
    try:
        TimeThread = Thread(target=checkNow,args=[CAP,] ,name='TimeCheck')
        TimeThread.start()
        app.run(host='192.168.0.100', debug=False, threaded=True)
    except :
        print('in exception')
    finally:
        FLAG_FOR_TIME_THREAD=False
        print('in main finally')
        print(len(TEMPERATURE),len(TIME_FOR_TEMP))
        logfile = open('temprature_logs.csv','a+')
        for timex,tempx,memory,cpu in zip(TIME_FOR_TEMP,TEMPERATURE,VIRTUAL_MEMORY,CPU_USAGE):
            logfile.write(f'{timex},{tempx},{memory},{cpu}\n')
        logfile.close()
        CAP.vs.release()
        CAP.endthread=True
        exit()
```

Comment: How exactly did you deploy. Did you use gunicorn or anything as such?
If so, the `if __name__ == '__main__'` block won't be executed since gunicorn only takes the app object from the file.

Comment: Actually I have been using it on development server itself. None of the production server used. Because I need some of those methods to run before app.run()